# How do I correctly set up WXWidgets on Ubuntu? My editor tells me the header files are incorrect

Tags: installation, header, wxwidgets

I wanted to try out the WXWidgets Hello World example (https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/overview_helloworld.html) so I followed the recommended practice on the Downloads page and installed the WXGTK package for my distribution, Ubuntu, which appears to be `libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev`. After doing this, and copying the example code, `g++` (installed from `build-essentials`) throws an error when I attempt to compile the program:

```
wxtest.cpp:4:10: fatal error: wx/wxprec.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <wx/wxprec.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

My editor (VSCode) also shows me an error: `cannot open source file "wx/wxprec.h"`.

This appears to be related to the fact that the WXWidgets header files are installed to the folder `wx-3.0/wx` instead of `wx`, but after changing `#include <wx/wxprec.h>` to `#include <wx-3.0/wx/wxprec.h>` I still get an error:

```
In file included from wxtest.cpp:4:
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/wxprec.h:12:10: fatal error: wx/defs.h: No such file or directory
   12 | #include "wx/defs.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

What am I doing wrong? How can these files be put in the right place?

Comment: what exact command did you try to use to build it? Can you open the Terminal and issue following `wx-config --version`? What is the output?

Comment: I used the command `sudo apt install libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev`. `wx-config --version` outputs `3.0.4`

Comment: and what command did you use to build the example? I presume you tried it in the Terminal...

Comment: `g++ example.cpp`

Comment: try ``g++ -o example `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` example.cpp``

Answer (score 0):

See the [building your project](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2/plat_gtk_install.html#gtk_new_project) section of the docs.